# Javascript OOP: Passing a value to property through input fails

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I`m learning and training js oop right now but I have an issue. I want to pass a value to property from a constructor by input value.For example if the user want to make his own character , he has to input name , age ,etc etc... but my code fails.Here's my js and html code.I've searched for the answer in the stackoverflow but couldn't find any answers to my question.

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var button = document.getElementById('action');
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('charName').value;
    var ageInput = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var par = document.getElementById('result');

    function Person(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    var first = new Person(nameInput,ageInput);

    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        par.innerHTML = first.name + ' ' + first.age;  
    });


});
```

HTML:

```
 <h1>Javascript Found</h1>
       <button id="action">Action</button>
       <div id="holder">
           <p>
               Give a name:<input type="text" id="charName" placeholder="Enter a name">   
           </p>
           <p>
              Enter age: <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter a number(0-100)">
           </p>
            <p id="result"></p>
       </div>
```

Comment: _my code fails_ is not a useful console error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the value from the input on click not before that otherwise it will use the old value which would be an empty string.

I changed the code so `nameInput` and `ageInput` refer to the elements and the value is then fetch inside the `Person` class and `first` is created on click.

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8yf0z3k/) to see it working.

```
var button = document.getElementById('action');
var nameInput = document.getElementById('charName');
var ageInput = document.getElementById('age');
var par = document.getElementById('result');

function Person(name,age){
  this.name = name.value;
  this.age = age.value;
}

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var first = new Person(nameInput, ageInput);
  console.log(first);
  par.innerHTML = first.name + ' ' + first.age;  
});
```

Comment: Thank you , you helped me a lot ! :) God Bless you brother.

Comment: btw can I ask you one more thing? why when I put nameInput.value, ageInput.value,  it shows undefined undefined , shouldn't I read the value of the input?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the click listener is executed correctly, but the values of first.name and first.age are ''. You can verify that by putting a console.log(first) in the click listener.

So why is that? At the time your DOMContentLoaded listener triggers, both your inputs are empty (value == ''). Now, you **copy** these values into an instance of Person. Next, you wait for clicked events which are triggered at some point but the value of name and age in your instance were not updated so they are still "". So you set par.innerHTML = ' '.

What you need to do is, you have to read the values of your inputs again and update the variables in your instance before you set par.innerHTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Hey, btw can I ask you one more thing? why when I put new Person( nameInput.value, ageInput.value), it shows undefined undefined , shouldn't I read the value of the input with .value , when it's new Person(nameInput, ageInput) works? kinda strange why is that behavior

Comment: Try to add a value="" attribute to your inputs, that might help.